# Trouble With retrieving Session Attributes after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, struts2-jquery

I am trying to set some variables in session through an ajax call in my jsp and  I am trying to retrieve these values in the same jsp page.

Problem is that I am not getting these values once the JSP page is rendered,but once I refresh the page these values are accessible.How it is happening?

P.S- I cannot put a reload method as it changes my other variables state.

Here is my JSP page

```
function call() {

//LocalStorage = new LocalStorage();
var Request_id= <%=session.getAttribute("Request_id")%>;

var tabIndex=0;
var source=1;
var action = "queryinterfaceresults_getStatus.action";
var serializedForm ="&Request_id="+Request_id;
alert(Request_id+":::Request_id");
$.ajax({
      url: action,
      type:"POST",
      data:serializedForm,
      success: function(data){
          alert(data)
        var matchcount  = <%=session.getAttribute("matchcount")%>;
        var postedcount = <%=session.getAttribute("postedcount")%>;
        var completedcount = <%=session.getAttribute("completedcount")%>;

        if(postedcount!=null && completedcount!=null && postedcount == completedcount  )
        {
            alert("PostedCount::: "+postedcount)
            alert("Completedcount::: "+completedcount)
            getRequestHistoryDetails(matchcount,postedcount,completedcount,source,Request_id);
        }  
        else if(postedcount!=completedcount  )
        {

            alert("ElsePostedCount::::"+postedcount)
            alert("ElsecompletedCount::::"+completedcount)
             //alert("p");
               //d1 = new Date();  
                /* var difference = d1.getTime() - d.getTime();
               var minutesDifference = Math.floor(((difference/1000)/60));
                       difference -= minutesDifference*1000*60; 
               alert("min.00000000000000000diff::::"+minutesDifference );
                        var secondsDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000);
                     //  difference -= secondsDifference*1000 */
              // alert("secondsDifference::::"+secondsDifference ); 
            /*  if(secondsDifference>60)
                {
                    $('#loadingImage').hide();
                    alert("More Parameters are required or a tighter profile needs to be used.");
                }*/


                /* {
                    call() ;        
                }   */

        }
        /*  else if($('#status').val()!=null && $('#status').val()=='e' )
        {
                    //alert("Error in primematch!!!!"); 
                    $("#message").hide();
                    $("#error").html("<font color='red'; fontsize='10px';>Error in Service, Please repost!!!</font>");
                    $("#QueryInterfaceResults").hide();

        } */


        },
        error: function(e,request){
            console.log("error",$('#status').val())
            <%--  alert("Problem in citizen matches");
           window.location.href = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.jsp"; --%>
}
});
```

}

and the action class method

```
public String getStatus() {



        logger.info("In getStatus():::::::::::::::" + getRequest_id());
        QueryInterfaceResultsManager manager = QueryInterfaceResultsManager.getInstance();
        try {
            RequestStatus requestStatus = manager.getStatus(getRequest_id().toString().trim());
            logger.info("requeststatus :: "+requestStatus);
            logger.info("requestStatus.getPostedCount() :: "+requestStatus.getPostedCount());

            if (requestStatus != null) {
                logger.info("requestStatus in if "+requestStatus);



                session.put("postedcount", "1");//requestStatus.getPostedCount());
                session.put("completedcount", "1");//requestStatus.getCompletedCount());
                session.put("matchcount", "1");//requestStatus.getMatchCount());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while getting ststus::" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return "statuspage";

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You load a page, make an Ajax call that sets session variable(s)... if you don't do anything on the page how would the page know that something on the server side happened? Those session variables in your JS are rendered when the page is received by the client--the page (or portion thereof) is not magically re-rendered  because you've made an Ajax call.

Comment: @DaveNewton Then what approach shall I take?...and I want the dynamic data loading then How should I do it?....Also,what is the use of AJAX then?

Comment: What's the use of Ajax?! If you want to do something on the client side you need to return something in your Ajax then do something with it.